# C++ Random Int number, outputs same number to each record on output file

Tags: c++, file, random, file-handling

I want to generate a random number every time the program is run. I will output it to a file using ofstream. However, I have checked the file and the same number is returned. Does anyone know why my code below does not generate a random number within the bounds everything it is run? I think it static but not sure why.

```
int tempJ = rand() % 10000;
```

Comment: you need to seed first using [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand)

Comment: do you use `srand()` to seed the rng?

Comment: btw getting the same number every time is just as random as getting a different number every time, but you are probably right, that it actually isnt random

Comment: @tobi303 [It can happen](http://2we26u4fam7n16rz3a44uhbe1bq2.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/121411_1611_SecureRando1.png)

Comment: humans tend to see patterns everywhere, but the sequence 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 is just as likely to appear as 3 2 5 9 1 6 3 4 7. Anyhow if you want random numbers you should use `<random>` and not `rand()`.

Comment: Try using the C++ Standard Library pseudorandom number library. Ther'es a good example on this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: As a side note: The reason it generates the same sequence each time is so that you can test your code. A random sequence that changes is hard to use in your unit tests.